# Symfony2 how to change bundle format once the bundle is generated?

Tags: php, symfony

If you generated a bundle using the command line is it possible to change the format?

There are 4 formats if I am correct.

- yml
- annotation
- php
- xml

For example I generated the bundle when following the tutorial. However I mistakenly picked the default annotation format while I should have chosen the yml format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as a variant (as I recognized correct), you can manually write (for example) yml configuration.

Just create file in 
`YourBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml` with the necessary records, and reg it in `app\config\routing.yml` :

`YourBundle:`

```
    resource: "@YourBundle\Resources\config\routing.yml"
    prefix: /prefix
```

Or you can write routing directly inside main routing file (in app folder).